# IntelliJ giving error while running JUnit Tests. Test framework quit expectedly

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to run JUnit test cases directly from IntelliJ by clicking on the play button just on the side of the Test class name but it's giving the error :

**Error: Could not find or load main class @C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file824368105**

The test cases are working fine while running using maven. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: The `idea_arg_file` includes a list of classpaths and java can't find our main class in that list. It's hard to say why it can't find the main class in it without an example project. You may change the `Shorten command line` to `None` in the run configuration and rerun it, check all the classpaths in the output's first command to see if the classpath doesn't include your main compiled classpath. You could also try the IDE main menu `Help | Contact Support` to contact the IntelliJ team with a sample project or more details for help.

Comment: @LJreplica I checked the run configuration and found that the Shorten Command Line option was set to None. So I changed it to using JAR Manifest and it worked.